# ¿Como puedo transformar un serializeArray() en un Objeto en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola a todos quisiera saber como puedo transformar un serializeArray() en un objeto javascript

```
function guardar(){
    var datos = $('.habInputs').serializeArray()
    $.ajax({
    url: 'controlador/guardar',
    type: 'POST',
    data: datos})
```

el serializeArray() está capturando todos los valores que tengan los inputs que tienen la clase .habInputs esto lo hice así para para ser selectivo con respecto a los inputs que quiero guardar (No requiero de guardar todos los inputs que tengo)
como resultado del serializeArray() me devuelve la siguiente salida:

[image: Salida del SerializeArray()]

la razón por la que quiero pasar esto a un objeto es para poder manipular mejor los datos, es decir quiero que el array que está en la variable datos pase a ser algo como esto

```
datos = {
          0: { item: 1,
               usuario: 1,
               obs: "prueba2"},
          1: {
               item: 2,
               usuario: 472,
               obs: "preubas1"},
          2: {
               item: 30,
               usuario: 393,
               obs: "pruebas2"}
          }
```

De esta manera al recibirlos en php puedo recorrerlos y enviarlos mas facil a mi bd. (para enteder mejor supongamos que cada indice como 0, 1 o 2 seria una fila en una tabla en bd.

¿hay alguna manera de solventar el problema o algún método alternativo?

Comment: debes colocar un ejemplo minimo verificable...

Answer (score 1):

Ya que se repiten los atributos *name*, de preferencia, deberías agregar corchetes, por ejemplo: `<input class="habInputs" name="item[]" value="1">`, aunque no es realmente necesario.

Para lograr la estructura deseada, no se pueden seleccionar los campos por clase, sino por nombre. Hay la misma cantidad de campos por cada nombre y se pueden acceder por posición, recorriendo uno de ellos con [$.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) y obteniendo los otros por posición con [$.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```js
// Definir arreglo vacío
let obj = [];
// Recorrer todos los checkbox
$('[name="habilitado"]').each(function(index) {
    // Solo si está marcado
    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
        // Agregar al arreglo
        obj.push({
            item: $('[name="item"]').eq(index).val(),
            usuario: $('[name="usuario"]').eq(index).val(),
            obs: $('[name="obs"]').eq(index).val(),
        });
    }
});

// Al final, tienes un arreglo (objeto iterable) de objetos con la estructura deseada
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="habilitado" checked>
<input class="habInputs" name="item" value="1">
<input class="habInputs" name="usuario" value="1">
<input class="habInputs" name="obs" value="prueba2"><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="habilitado">
<input class="habInputs" name="item" value="2">
<input class="habInputs" name="usuario" value="472">
<input class="habInputs" name="obs" value="pruebas1"><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="habilitado" checked>
<input class="habInputs" name="item" value="30">
<input class="habInputs" name="usuario" value="393">
<input class="habInputs" name="obs" value="pruebas2"><br>
```

**Opción sin *jQuery*:**

Sería más rápido porque desde un inicio tienes todos los campos, cada uno en un [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList) y no es necesario hacer que el navegador (o jQuery) identifique cada uno dentro del ciclo.

En caso de que agregues filas de forma dinámica, solo habría que actualizar esas variables.

**Nota:** Con *jQuery* podrías usar el método [$.toArray()](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) para obtener el mismo comportamiento, pero sigo teniendo mis dudas respecto a uso de memoria y rendimiento. Ya lo dejo a tu criterio.

```js
// Obtener primero todos los campos necesarios
let checks = document.querySelectorAll('[name="habilitado"]');
let items = document.querySelectorAll('[name="item"]');
let usuarios = document.querySelectorAll('[name="usuario"]');
let obs = document.querySelectorAll('[name="obs"]');

function generaObjeto() {
    // Crear arreglo vacío
    let obj = [];

    // Recorrer checkboxes y usar índice para acceder a los otros campos
    checks.forEach((check, index) => {
        if(check.checked) {
            obj.push({
                item: items[index].value,
                usuario: usuarios[index].value,
                obs: obs[index].value
            });
        }
    });
    return obj;
}

// Usar los checkboxes para habilitar o deshabilitar campos
function checkCambia(index) {
    let disabled = !checks[index].checked;
    items[index].disabled = disabled;
    usuarios[index].disabled = disabled;
    obs[index].disabled = disabled;
}

// Asignar evento a los checkbox
checks.forEach((check, index) => {
    check.addEventListener('change', () => checkCambia(index));
});

// Asignar evento para generar objeto
document.querySelector('#generar').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(generaObjeto());
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="habilitado" checked>
<input class="habInputs" name="item" value="1">
<input class="habInputs" name="usuario" value="1">
<input class="habInputs" name="obs" value="prueba2"><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="habilitado">
<input class="habInputs" name="item" value="2" disabled>
<input class="habInputs" name="usuario" value="472" disabled>
<input class="habInputs" name="obs" value="pruebas1" disabled><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="habilitado" checked>
<input class="habInputs" name="item" value="30">
<input class="habInputs" name="usuario" value="393">
<input class="habInputs" name="obs" value="pruebas2"><br>

<button id="generar">Generar objeto</button>
```

Comment: La razón por la que lo hice mediante una clase es para no recorrerlos todo los inputs, mi clase permite mediante el serializeArray() tomar todos esos valores sin necesidad de usar un ciclo, esto me ayuda a que vaya mas rápido la vista

Comment: @Sairento, de cualquier forma, se tiene que recorrer en un ciclo y, lo más fácil, es hacerlo por índice de un campo, de lo contrario, se tendría que aplicar una lógica _muy "ilógica"_ con contadores y condicionales; dudo mucho que eso resulte _"más rápido a la vista"_, aunque deberías especificar a qué te refieres con eso.

Comment: Antes recorría de una manera muy similar a como muestra tu ejemplo, la diferencia es que yo recorria por id utilizando un ciclo for, el problema estaba que este recorria todo los inputs de la vista incluyendo algunos inputs que no iba guardar sus datos, lo que hacía era validar uno por uno si el input estaba habilitado medianto un check si ese input estaba habilitado para que el usuario digite y guarde pero como decía esto debía validar por todos los inputs haciendo que se tardara mucho (la cantidad de  inputs puede variar dependiendo de lo que uno quiera pueden haber como 10 inputs o 100)

Comment: Al final terminé optando por el serialize() que solo con ponerle la clase a los inputs este los iba tomar tanto el name como el value de ese input que tuviera esa clase en terminos mas simples si tengo 100 inputs y checkeo o habilito solo 3 al chekear esos 3 inputs se les agrega una clase (en este caso a la que yo llamo .habInputs) solo los 3 inputs checkeados tendran esa clase y por mediante esa clase obtendré su name y su valor (como se muestra en la imagen que compartí) eso me permite no utilizar un ciclo en mi codigo para capturar los valores uno por uno y así vaya mas rápido

Comment: ¿Tienes un _checkbox_ para saber si la fila está habilitada? Entonces se puede hacer el ciclo sobre los que estén marcados. Sí, `serializeArray()` te evita hacer un ciclo, pero nunca te va a dar el resultado que esperas.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta actualizada, es más apropiada que la anterior y realmente no debería tomar demasiado tiempo si hay 10 o 100 conjuntos para analizar y, si tarda mucho, considera generar el objeto sin _jQuery_, eso sí agilizaría el proceso.

Answer (score 0):

yo lo solucionaría de la siguiente manera

Crear un objeto limpio

```
var newObj = {};
var kvArray = [{clave:1, valor:10}, {clave:2, valor:20}, {clave:3, valor: 30}];
```

Recorrer cada elemento de tu kvArray, con newObj['index o cualquier nombre'] puedes agregar valores al objeto sin la necesidad de que la el objeto ya cuente con dicha propiedad, exista o no lo va a agregar.

```
kvArray.forEach((element, index) => {
 newObj[index] = { '0': element.clave, '1': element.valor};
});
```

Con un log podemos apreciar la salida:

```
console.log(newObj);

{
 '0': { '0': 1, '1': 10 },
 '1': { '0': 2, '1': 20 },
 '2': { '0': 3, '1': 30 }
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Me parece interesante esta manera pero tengo una duda al respecto. En mi caso el indice name corresponde al nombre que debe tener ese indice, es decir usando tu ejemplo tienes un indice llamado clave pero realmente no quiero que este sea llamado clave si no 1.
otro ejemplo seria en mi caso name: "item", cuando debería ser item: 1
O en tu caso: 1: 10 (1 pertenece al indice clave y 10 a su valor)

Comment: Quiere decir que te gustaría cambiar el nombre de las propiedades de tu objeto a:

{ "0": 1, "1": 10  },
{ "0": 2, "1": 20  }

Es eso?

Comment: Exactamente, me gustaría cambiar el nombre así como muestras en tu comentario

Comment: listo, dentro del foreach actualicé la línea al igual que el resultado